# ProtractorJS: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "Could not find testability for element."

Tags: selenium, angular, jasmine, protractor

I'm trying to end-to-end test my Angular 2 project with ProtractorJS.
When I run `protractor conf.js` in my console, I get:

```
 Failed: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "Could not
 find testability for element."
```

Inside the config file:

```
exports.config = {
    seleniumAddress: "http://localhost:4444/wd/hub",
    framework:"jasmine2",
    capabilities: {"browserName": "chrome"},
    specs: ["todo-spec.js"]
};
```

My root component:

```
<section>
    <h1>Employee Payroll Information Directory</h1>
    <employee-searchform></employee-searchform>
</section>
```

This is the test I'm trying to run:

```
describe('modal component', function () {
    it('should output the employee and delete it from the array', function () {
        browser.get('http://localhost:80/Fourth/Fourth/');
        var searchField = element(by.className('.ng-valid'));
        searchField.click();
        searchField.sendKeys('Skye');
        searchField.getText().then(function (text) {
            console.log(text);
        });
        var employeeListItem = element(by.id('employee-list'));
    });
});
```

This is what I get on the webDriver Selenium server:

```
23:57:25.816 INFO - Done: [execute async script: try { return (function (rootSel
ector, callback) {
  var el = document.querySelector(rootSelector);

  try {
    if (window.getAngularTestability) {
      window.getAngularTestability(el).whenStable(callback);
      return;
    }
    if (!window.angular) {
      throw new Error('angular could not be found on the window');
    }
    if (angular.getTestability) {
      angular.getTestability(el).whenStable(callback);
    } else {
      if (!angular.element(el).injector()) {
        throw new Error('root element (' + rootSelector + ') has no injector.' +

           ' this may mean it is not inside ng-app.');
      }
      angular.element(el).injector().get('$browser').
          notifyWhenNoOutstandingRequests(callback);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    callback(err.message);
  }
}).apply(this, arguments); }
catch(e) { throw (e instanceof Error) ? e : new Error(e); }, [body]]
23:57:25.899 INFO - Executing: [delete session: 35adb055-eee3-419e-b3c1-461b65b4
18aa])
23:57:29.157 INFO - Done: [delete session: 35adb055-eee3-419e-b3c1-461b65b418aa]
```

Comment: @alecxe Just added it.

Comment: @alecxe This is Angular 2. My main component is on an `<app>`custom tag

Comment: What protractor version are you using?

Comment: @alecxe Latest - 4.0.3

Comment: Thanks, what if you add `rootElement: 'app'` to your protractor config?

Comment: @alecxe What you suggested actually worked, but now I get `Failed: No element found using locator: By.className(".ng-valid")`. My locator isn't working for some reason and the element is definitely there onload. Do you know why I'm not selecting it right? I'll try selecting it in a different way

Comment: `ng-valid` is, generally speaking, not a good class name to base your locator on. Is your element inside the `app` element? Could you show its html representation? Thanks.

Comment: It actually worked this time. Write me an answer, that would help others about how to specify the root component explicitly in the `conf.js` and I'll select it and upvote it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should point Protractor to the element housing the Angular app. This can be done by setting the [`rootElement`](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/referenceConf.js#L213) in your protractor config:

```
rootElement: 'app',
```

Answer (score -1):

if you use `By.className()` you no need to mention "." in front of your class name. You can simply use `By.className("ng-valid")`